# Why are the values in my hash map different than what was put in?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a hash map that seems to be altering the values that I store in it. Almost all of my keys are mapping correctly; however, there are about 4 or 5 keys whose values are completely different in the `entrySet()` than what was actually put inside of them. I'm at a complete loss.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  HashMap<Character, Integer> map = make_map();
  System.out.print(map.entrySet());

}

public static HashMap<Character,Integer> make_map(){
  HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();


  map.put('a',100000);
  map.put('b',110000);
  map.put('c',100100);
  map.put('d',100110);
  map.put('e',100010);

  map.put('f',110100);
  map.put('g',110110);
  map.put('h',110010);
  map.put('i',010100);
  map.put('j',010110);

  map.put('k',101000);
  map.put('l',111000);
  map.put('m',101100);
  map.put('n',101110);
  map.put('o',101010);

  map.put('p',111100);
  map.put('q',111110);
  map.put('r',111010);
  map.put('s',011100);
  map.put('t',011110);

  map.put('u',101001);
  map.put('v',111001);
  map.put('w',010111);
  map.put('x',101101);

  map.put('y',101111);
  map.put('z',101011);
  map.put(' ',000000);



  return map;

}
```

I noticed a few of my conditions were failing for some reason, then when I printed out the `entrySet()` I noticed keys like 'i' were being mapped to 4160, even though I clearly put `010100`. Also, 'j' gives me a bogus result with 4160 too.  The others are fine...and then once again characters 'w' and a few others are mapped to 4 digit numbers that begin with 4.

Here's the whole entry set:

```
[ =0, a=100000, b=110000, c=100100, d=100110, e=100010, f=110100, g=110110, h=110010, i=4160, j=4168, k=101000, l=111000, m=101100, n=101110, o=101010, p=111100, q=111110, r=111010, s=4672, t=4680, u=101001, v=111001, w=4169, x=101101, y=101111, z=101011]
```

As you can see, 't', and 's' are not as intended as well as the others previously mentioned. What's going on?

Comment: Numeric literals starting in 0 are parsed as octal numbers (base 8). Perhaps you should use a `HashMap<Character, String>`.

Comment: The duplicate explains *why* the results come up that way, but don't really offer any solution as to what to do to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered, there's an issue with putting a leading zero in front of an integer; Java will treat it as an octal number, which is base-8.

This is the *first* problem.  The numbers you're putting in there are *not* base-2 like you intended, but they *are* base-8.

That's easily solved; you would simply have to ensure that the numbers are parsed as binary when you place them into your map.

```
map.put('a', Integer.parseInt("100000", 2));
```

*Printing* these numbers will give you their full integer representation.  This is the *second* problem; printing out collections does not translate or format the data in any other form besides the standard numerical-type representation.

If you want to print them as hex values, you'll need to make use of `Integer.toBinaryString`.

This too is easily accomplished with Java 8's Stream API.

```
map.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> System.out.printf("%s=%s ", entry.getKey(), Integer.toBinaryString(entry.getValue())));
```

Answer (score 1):

You see this result, because your values start with `0` and represent as octal numbers, base 8.